# EF Include() with AsNoTracking

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, include

I have this linq query:

```
database.EmployeeHistory.AsNoTracking()
.Include("Employee.Orders")
.Include("Employee.Books").AsNoTracking()
```

This works except that saving the changes I made for Employee.Orders is not working. Does this means that even I did not add the AsNoTracking for Employee.Orders it is also not tracked?

Comment: `AsNoTracking` is a query level option. It affects all the entities returned by the query.

Comment: As the `EmployeeHistory` doesn't cached the `Employee.Orders` will not be cached as well.

Answer (score 1):

AsNoTracking means that any changes you make to the entity(s) are not tracked by the change tracker and will not be picked up when you call SaveChanges().

AsNoTracking() is meant for read-only scenarios. In this case, your entities are not tracked by the context and should help with memory usage & performance.

In your case, remove AsNoTracking() and try to save again.